# jQuery jqXHR - cancel chained calls, trigger error chain

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.5, jquery-deferred

I am creating a ajax utility for interfacing with my server methods. I would like to leverage jQuery 1.5+ deferred methods from the object returned from the jQuery.ajax() call. The situation is following.

1. The serverside method always returns a JSON object:

   `{ success: true|false, data: ... }`
2. The client-side utility initiates the ajax call like this

   `var jqxhr = $.ajax({ ... });`
3. And the problem area:

   ```
   jqxhr.success(function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        if(!data || !data.success) { 
            ???? // abort processing, trigger error
        }
   });
   return jqxhr; // return to caller so he can attach his own handlers
   ```

So the question is how to cancel invocation of all the callers appended success callbacks an trigger his error handler in the place mentioned with `????` ?

The documentation says the deferred function invocation lists are FIFO, so my success handler is definitely the first one.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

(**UPDATE:**
Please note that currently jQuery Promises are not compatible with the [Promises/A+ specification](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/) - more info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success/5316805#5316805).)

In your function where you create the AJAX request you can also create a deferred object and return a promise to the caller after binding its resolve and reject functions to the appropriate callbacks of the $.ajax request with some custom data verification, like this:

```
function makerequest() {

    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var promise = deferred.promise();

    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        // ...
    });

    jqxhr.success(function(data, status, xhr) {
        if (!data || !data.success) {
            deferred.reject(jqxhr, 'error');
        } else {
            deferred.resolve(data, status, xhr);
        }
    });

    jqxhr.error(function(jqXHR, status, error) {
        deferred.reject(jqXHR, status, error);
    });

    return promise;
}
```

Now anyone will be able to use it like any promise like this to your function:

```
var request = makerequest();

request.done(successCallback);
request.fail(errorCallback);
```

Or even just:

```
makerequest().then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

If you also add this:

```
    promise.success = promise.done;
    promise.error = promise.fail;
```

then your caller will have (maybe more familiar) interface of .success() and .error() like with pure $.ajax() calls:

```
var request = makerequest();

request.success(successCallback);
request.error(errorCallback);
```

(The implementation of .complete() is left as an exercise for the reader.)

See this demos:

- http://jsfiddle.net/_rsp/r2YnM/
- http://jsfiddle.net/_rsp/r2YnM/1/ (more verbose)

Here's another example pulled directly from a working project:

```
function ajax(url, data) {
    var self = this;
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var promise = deferred.promise();

    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST'
    }).done(function (msg, status, xhr) {
        if (!msg || msg.Error) {
            self.doError(msg.Error);
            deferred.reject(jqxhr, 'error');
        } else {
            deferred.resolve(msg, status, xhr);
        }
    });

    return promise;
}
```

Comment: **PLEASE NOTE**: This answer is dated Feb '11, at which time jQuery was at v1.5. Subsequent improvements to jQuery make this answer redundant. From v1.6, the generally accepted solution would have involved `deferred.pipe()` and from v1.8 `deferred.then()`, at which point we would write something like `function makerequest() { return jqxhr.then(function(data) { return (data && data.success) ? jqxhr : $.Deferred().reject(new Error('AJAX data error')).promise(); }); }`.

Comment: As soon as we start returning something not equals to `jqXHR` (like `$.Deferred().promise` in the answer above), we loose access to `.abort()` function of original `jqXHR` object and can't abort the request before it gets resolved anymore, if required.