# JavaScript function that returns AJAX call data

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I would like to create a JavaScript function which returns the value of a jQuery AJAX call. I would like something like this.

```
function checkUserIdExists(userid){
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'theurl',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        data: {
           userid: userid
        },
        success: function(data){
            return data;
        }
    });
}
```

I know I can do this by setting async to false but I would rather not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With jQuery 1.5, you can use the brand-new [`$.Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) feature, which is meant for exactly this.

> ```
> // Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
> // and remember the jqxhr object for this request
> var jqxhr = $.ajax({ url: "example.php" })
>     .success(function() { alert("success"); })
>     .error(function() { alert("error"); })
>     .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
>
> // perform other work here ...
>
> // Set another completion function for the request above
> jqxhr.complete(function(){ alert("second complete"); });
> ```

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)

Comment: how to read json data from this variable jqxhr

Answer (score 32):

You can't return data returned by an AJAX call unless you want to call it synchronously (and you don't – trust me). But what you can return is a *promise* of a data returned by an AJAX call and you can do it actually in a very elegant way.

(**UPDATE:**
Please note that currently jQuery Promises are not compatible with the [Promises/A+ specification](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/) - more info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success/5316805#5316805).)

Basically you can return the return value of your $.ajax(...) call:

```
function checkUserIdExists(userid){
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'theurl',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        data: {
           userid: userid
        }
    });
}
```

and someone who calls your function can use it like this:

```
checkUserIdExists(userid).success(function (data) {
    // do something with data
});
```

See [this post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111695/jquery-jqxhr-cancel-chained-calls-trigger-error-chain/5112734#5112734) for a better explanation and demos if you are interested.

Comment: +1. A less-lazy version of my answer :)

Answer (score 16):

you can pass in a callback function:

```
function checkUserIdExists(userid, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: callback
    });
}

checkUserIdExists(4, function(data) {

});
```

Comment: +1 - This is what I was thinking, but in a clean, concise code example.

Comment: There is an important thing in here. You must add `async: false` property in `$.ajax` method. If not you don't get data into `global var`. That's an additional info.

Comment: Why is this a good answer? The op asked how to return a value, and this code returns nothing at all.

Answer (score 8):

As of jQuery 1.8, the "success", "error" and "complete" callback are deprecated. Instead you should be using "done", "fail" and "always".

So you could have:

```
function checkUserIdExists(userid, callback) {
        return $.ajax({
        url: 'theurl',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        data: {
           userid: userid
        }
    })
    .done(callback)
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Handle error
    });
}

checkUserIdExists(2, function(data) {
    console.log(data); // Do what you want with the data returned
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't how JavaScript asynchronous programming was really meant to be done.  Instead, use a callback in your success function to call another function to use your data returned from the server.

Comment: +1 for thinking what i was thinking

Answer (score 2):

Tim, the two scenarios are mutually exclusive; an asynchronous operation will not serve any purpose for, nor will it be able to retrieve returned data.

You should look at an event-enabled infrastructure for your ajax calls