# Returning Json to javascript

Tags: asp.net, json

I make a Json call to an ashx handler like this:

```
    attributes = $("#pageHtmlTag").attr("class").trim();
urlToHandler = 'JSonTestHandler.ashx';
jsonData = '{' + attributes + '}';

$.ajax({
    url: urlToHandler,
    data: jsonData,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {
        setAutocompleteData(data.responseDateTime);
        $("body").add("<div>" + data.toString() + " </div>").appendTo(document.body);
        alert("grate suceees");
    },
    error: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
        alert('There was an error.' + jqXHR);
    }
}); // end $.ajax
```

I receieve it and proccess it. I also want to send back some HTML to be displayed but i dont know how to send html back to the Jscript.

ashx:

```
    string jsonData = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();

.............................

        var testResultReportString = testResultReport.GetReportHtml();

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var jSonTestResultReport = serializer.Serialize(testResultReportString);

        context.Response.Write(jSonTestResultReport);
```

So the question is. How do i return data to the Ajax calls success function?

Answer (score 0):

You could return your data as JSON object:

```
var outputObject = "{ html = '" + jSonTestResultReport  + "' + someOtherData = ... + "}";
context.Response.Write(outputObject);
```

and access them in success function like this:

```
data.html and data.someOtherData
```

Comment: Its not working. I get the error in a Alert popoup:

Syntax error. Unexpected token = 

The output i send back is:
{ "resultReport" = " <li style="color:green;">js</li> " }

Comment: Oh i figured it out. I used an = instead of an :

Answer (score 0):

In application i am useing like this it's below i am showing all me state data with country id and that data bind to the state dropdownlist like this ..

```
StateData objStateData = new StateData();
            LMGDAL.db_LMGEntities dbData = new db_LMGEntities();               
            var data = (from con in dbData.tblStates
                        where con.State_CountryID == ID
                        select new StateData
                        {
                            StateID = con.StateID,
                            StateName = con.StateName
                        }).ToList();
            return data.ToArray();
```

and also create a new class in inside that .ashx file

```
[Serializable]
    public class StateData
    {
        public int StateID { get; set; }
        public string StateName { get; set; }
    }
```

and in my form

```
$("#ddlCountry").change(function () {
            var countryID = $("#ddlCountry").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "JsonData.asmx/GetStateByCountryID",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: '{ID:"' + countryID + '"}',
                success: function (msg) {
                    var data = msg.d;
                    var stateData = "";
                    $.each(data, function (index, itemdata) {
                        stateData += "<option  value='" + itemdata.StateID + "' > " + itemdata.StateName + " </option>";
                    });
                    $("#ddlState").empty();
                    $("#ddlState").append("<option value='0'>-Select State-</option>");

                    $("#ddlState").append(stateData);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Faild To Retrieve States.');
                }
            });
        });
```

i think this will help you.....

Answer (score 0):

You can't return data returned by an AJAX call because your data is not available immediately after the call to `$.ajax` as it is asynchronous. What you can return is a promise of a data returned by an AJAX call. A promise is a nice abstraction for functions to say: I can't return you the data because I don't have it yet and I don't want to block and make you wait so here's a promise instead and you'll be able to use it later, or to just give it to someone else and be done with it ([Callbacks, Promises, and Coroutines (oh my!): Asynchronous Programming Patterns in JavaScript](http://www.slideshare.net/domenicdenicola/callbacks-promises-and-coroutines-oh-my-the-evolution-of-asynchronicity-in-javascript)). For example, instead of:

```
$.ajax({
     url: urlToHandler,
     data: jsonData,
     dataType: 'json',
     type: 'POST',
     contentType: 'application/json',
     success: function (data) {
         setAutocompleteData(data.responseDateTime);
         $("body").add("<div>" + data.toString() + " </div>").appendTo(document.body);
         alert("great success");
     },
     error: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
         alert('There was an error.' + jqXHR);
     }
 }); // end $.ajax
```

you can return the return value of your `$.ajax(...)` call by writing your Ajax function like:

```
function testResultReportAjax() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: urlToHandler,
        data: jsonData,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        error: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
            alert('There was an error.' + jqXHR);
        }
    });
}
```

You get your promise by way of

```
var promise = testResultReportAjax();
```

which you can then use as an argument in function calls and use your data that is returned by the AJAX call:

```
promise.success(function (data) {
   alert(data);
});
```

You can view a [simple DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/rtjtm/). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5150650/122005) for a better explanation if needed.